# How to statistically compare categorical columns using python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, binary

I have computed some similarity scores using different methods such as cosine, Jaccard, using sentence transformers etc. The similarity score were then converted into binary form (x=1 if x>0.5, else 0).The output is as below:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        "q1": [
            "What is the step by step guide to invest in share market in india?",
            "What is the story of Kohinoor (Koh-i-Noor) Diamond?",
            "How can I increase the speed of my internet connection while using a VPN?",
            "Why am I mentally very lonely? How can I solve it?",
            "Which one dissolve in water quikly sugar, salt, methane and carbon di oxide?",
        ],
        "q2": [
            "What is the step by step guide to invest in share market?",
            "What would happen if the Indian government stole the Kohinoor (Koh-i-Noor) diamond back?",
            "How can Internet speed be increased by hacking through DNS?",
            "Find the remainder when [math]23^{24}[/math] is divided by 24,23?",
            "Which fish would survive in salt water?",
        ],
        "cos_sim": [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        "jac_sim": [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        "sentrf_sim": [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        "gensim_sim": [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    }
)
```

I want to statistically compare (more than taking just averages) the similarity flag columns among themselves. (`cos_sim`,`jac_sim`,`sentrf_sim`,`gensim_sim`).

Maybe some proportions etc.

Any inputs? Thanks

Comment: hello, can you please explain what is your desired output? i didn't understand what are you trying to do

Comment: "Statistically compare" is pretty vague.  What question(s) would you like to answer?  Are you trying to assess mutual agreement between pairs of similarity measures?  Are you trying to identify clusters of question pairs that have similar degrees of similarity?  Or something else?